# Approximate $_2F_1(a,b;c;x)$ for large (maybe negative) values of $a, b, c$?

Tags: asymptotics, hypergeometric-function

I need asymptotic approximations of the Hypergeometric function $_2F_1(a,b;c;x)$ for large positive values of $a, b, c$. Specifically, I need approximations for all the possible regimes, in which one or more of $a,b,c$ are greater than 100, and the others are positive and less than 100.

$x$ is in the range $0<x<1$.

Comment: What values of $x$ do you want? It makes a big difference if you want $x\approx 0$, $x\approx 1$, $x\approx\infty$, etc.

Comment: @Semiclassical I edited the question to include the range of $x$.